# Finding IP of device over GPRS/GSM

Tags: ip, gsm, pic, gprs

I am currently working on a hobby project where I am using a PIC controller and a sim900 modem for remote monitoring, over a GPRS connection.

I can upload data from my remote device on to the server in regular intervals.

Now I would like to send some control signals to the device from the server, but how do I find which device to send data to? I need to know the IP address of the device which is assigned dynamically.

Is there a static IP on GSM modem, or can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your service provider(SIM card providers) to assign a static IP for your SIM card.

Other option is you have to develop a simple application layer protocol for data transfer over TCP/UDP in which once the connection is established your modem should send its identity(Name/ID etc.)

On the server side you need to write the code in which you have to maintain a dynamic table of modem details and socket number. When the modem is connected you can send data over the same socket for control commands.